# How to make an interceptor asynchronous jwt angular

Tags: javascript, angular, jwt

I am trying to make an interceptor that handles the tokens, but I don't want to make unnecessary requests for refreshToken, that is, if I am already updating the token, I want the next request to wait until it  finishes updating the token and then send the request with the new token

What i tried so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { catchError, filter, map, switchMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private auth: AuthService,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    refreshingToken = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

        
        if (!this.auth.getToken()) {
            return next.handle(req)
        }

        const reqClone = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
            }
        })

        return next.handle(reqClone).pipe(
            catchError((err: any) => {

                //if error is about http
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

                    if (err.url.includes('refreshToken')) {
                        return next.handle(reqClone)
                    }

                    //if error is not about authorization 
                    if (err.status !== 401) {
                        return next.handle(reqClone)
                    }


                    if(this.refreshingToken.value === true){
                        return this.refreshingToken.pipe(
                            filter(value => value === false),
                            take(1),
                            switchMap((value)=>{
                                return next.handle(reqClone)
                            })
                        )
                    }else{
                        this.refreshingToken.next(true)
                        return this.renewToken(req).pipe(
                            switchMap(reqWithNewToken => {
                                this.refreshingToken.next(false)
                                return next.handle(reqWithNewToken)
                            })
                        )
                    }

                } else {
                    return next.handle(reqClone)
                }

            })
        )
    }

    renewToken(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}/refreshToken`, { withCredentials: true }).pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
                //update access token
                this.auth.setToken(res.token)
                return req.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        authorization: `Bearer ${res.token}`
                    }
                })
            })
        )
    }
}
```

the error:
[image: Image from Gyazo]